# run jar application on mac error 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion

i'm getting problem with java at mac osx lion but not all osx lion have problem..
my application include with java jre 1.8 to run the application. but i got error like this

> NSInvocation: warning: object of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead

how to handle that ? 
thanks